# Trying to understand more about operator associativity in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I got quite confusioned about *associativity* in OCaml.

Let's have some examples first.

**1. Is `+` left associative or right?**

I think it is left associative. which means if we have `a + b + c + d`, then it is `((a+b)+c)+d`.

But what if we do `f1 1 + f2 2`? Will it throw an error? because it should be `((f1 1)+f2) 2`, right?

**2. `::` is right associative, but what if used with `,`?**

If we do `4,3::[]`, then we have `[4,3]`. it will create a tuple `(4,3)`, then `::` into `[]`.

then why doesn't `4,3::5,6::[]` work?

**3. functions**

Say we have `let f x y = y x 5`, so `y` is a function taking two parameters.

If we do `f 1 + 2`, because `+` is actually a function taking two parameters, why won't `f 1 + 2` work? Why doesn't `+` become a parameter of `f`?

**4. right associativity**

How to create a infix function with right associativity?

---

Basically, I guess I haven't understood the whole associative / precedence thing in OCaml.

I know there are tables like this http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-caml-light/node4.9.html out there. But can someone explain more to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Operator associativity determines how to parse an expression when there are multiple operators with the same precedence. For example, `a + b + c` has two operators with the same precedence (`+` and `+`), so the associativity determines how to parse that expression: the operator is left-associative, so the expression is equivalent to `(a + b) + c`.

In the expression `f1 1 + f2 2`, juxtaposition (`f1 1` and `f2 2`) has higher precedence than `+`, so the expression is equivalent to `(f1 1) + (f2 2)`. There aren't two or more operators at the same precedence level, so associativity doesn't matter.

Your statement about `4,3::[]` is wrong: `::` has higher precedence than `,`, so it is parsed as `4, (3::[])`, not `(4,3)::[]`. The result is a pair whose second element is a list. Read the type error for `4,3::5,6::[]`: it is equivalent to `(4, (3::5), (6::[]))`, thus the compiler complains that `5` has type `int` but the context (due to the `::` operator) requires a list.

When you write `f 1 + 2`, it is parsed as `(f 1) + 2`. The function `f` is applied to an integer argument; since `f` expects two arguments, the result is a function (waiting for the second argument), but the `+` operator wants an integer, so the expression is ill-typed. `+` isn't a parameter of `f` because `+` by itself is not an expression, and the argument of a function is an expression.

I don't know what you mean by “infix function with right associative”. The associativity and precedence of operators in Ocaml is determined by the first character of the operator as indicated in the table you link to.

These are all standard concepts in parsing, applicable to almost every programming language out there. I recommend reading any textbook with a chapter on programming language syntax or parsing, or start with the Wikipedia articles on [associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) and [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).

Comment: in `f 1 + 2`, why it is not `(f 1 +) 2`? as `+` is a function itself. Maybe if `f 1 (+) 2`, then `(+)` will be considered as a parameter of `f`?

Comment: @JacksonTale `+` is the name of a function, but that name can only be used in an infix position. `+` is not an expression. `f 1 +` is not an expression either, so `(f 1 +) 2` is not valid syntax. `(+)` is an expression (any operator can be put in parentheses to form an expression). So `f 1 (+) 2` applies the function `f` to the three parameters `1`, `(+)` and `2`.

Comment: @JacksonTale: `+` is not an expression. `(+)` is an expression, whose value is a function.